# Identifying faces from the UV map

Tags: uv

A 3D model I work on seems to create some artifacts from the unwrap function:

[image]

These faces in a straight line don't seem to correlate with any faces I have actually wanted to have in the model, but I can't select vertices on the UV map and then see them marked on the main edit window - which makes hunting down these artifacts for removal seemingly impossible. So far I have tried to merge by distance for no result, they seem to be distributed all over the item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have got the *Sync Selection* button checked:

[image]

(The double arrow on the left)

Then, deselect all in the UV window, except the vertex of interest, mouse over the 3D View, and hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd> to hide all but your selection. Still no sight? Hit <kbd>Numpad  .</kbd>  (period) to center the view on the selection.

Comment: I ended up finding the artifact faces by spinning around the model, but indeed UV sync would have helped so much, and it'll be a goo tool in my box!